# Fail to install libsqlite3-dev (rvm requirements)

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rvm, apt

I've just moved to **Ubuntu 12.10** from Win7. Because Ruby development is a kind of pain on Win. But I get stuck on a first step on Ubuntu also.

First I got rvm as it described on rvm web site:

> \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s

And then this

> $ rvm requirements

gave me error and here is the log:

> ...
>
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.7.13-1) but 3.7.15.2-1~pub1 is to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I messing around with libsqlite3-dev and libsqlite3-0: re-installing, download and install via dpkg (and forcing instalation also). After one total system reinstall (desperade purge of libsqlite3-0, he-he), 7 hours, dozens web pages and zillions apt-get installs-purge-downloads I totaly don't know what to do. So I can provide any needed log output just don't know what exactly - I am very new in Linux.